# nodejs - how to give user acces only to his content

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

hello I've a board schema like this

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please check your name',
    trim: true,
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'no user specified'
  },
  private: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  cards: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card' }],
```

and card schema like this

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please check your name',
    trim: true,
  },
  position: {
    type: Number,
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
  },
  boardId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'Pleaae specify board id',
  },
```

I wrote this function ensure user will get only his boards

```
exports.gettingBoards = async function gettingBoards(req, res) {
  const user = req.user;
  const board = await Board.find({ userId: user.id });
  res.json(board);
};
```

I don't if it's the best way but it works , my problem right now is I want to make this to cards , but cards don't have userId propety on it , it's on their parent board , so what can I do , to ensure that no user can get card till it's his card ?

Comment: As I can see in your cards schema, you have userId there as well. Either I'm missing something or you paste wrong code in card schema.

Comment: i tried to do it like that , I ask about if it's the right way to do so

Comment: That will do. This is one of the ways to do so.